# 3D reconstruction from 2 images with baseline and single camera calibration

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

my semester project is to Calibrate Stereo Cameras with a big baseline (~2m).
so my approach is to run without exact defined calibration pattern like the chessboard cause it had to be huge and would be hard to handle.

my problem is similar to this: [3d reconstruction from 2 images without info about the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9026567/3858076)

Program till now:

- Corner detection left image  `goodFeaturesToTrack`
- refined corners  `cornerSubPix`
- Find corner locations in right image  `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`
- calculate fundamental matrix F  `findFundamentalMat`
- calculate H1, H2 rectification homography matrix  `stereoRectifyUncalibrated`
- Rectify images  `warpPerspective`
- Calculate Disparity map  `sgbm`

so far so good it works passably but rectified images are "jumping" in perspective if i change the number of corners..

don't know if this if form imprecision or mistakes i mad or if it cant be calculated due to no known camera parameters or no lens distortion compensation (but also happens on Tsukuba pics..)
suggestions are welcome :)

but not my main problem, now i want to reconstruct the 3D points.

but `reprojectImageTo3D` needs the Q matrix which i don't have so far. so my question is how to calculate it? i have the baseline, distance between the two cameras. My feeling says if i convert des disparity map in to a 3d point cloud the only thing im missing is the scale right? so if i set in the baseline i got the 3d reconstruction right? then how to?
im also planing to compensate lens distortion as the first step for each camera separately with a chessboard (small and close to one camera at a time so i haven't to be 10-15m away with a big pattern in the overlapping area of both..) so if this is helping i could also use the camera parameters..

is there a documentation besides the http://docs.opencv.org? that i can see and understand what and how the Q matrix is calculated or can i open the source code (probably hard to understand for me ^^) if i press F2 in Qt i only see the function with the transfer parameter types.. (sorry im really new to all of this )

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Wjc.jpg]

- left: input with found corners
- top h1, h2: rectify images (looks good with this corner count ^^)
- SGBM: Disparity map

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math rather than programming. Please refer to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @FinalContest thx i try it there a few programming questions are in my topic and would like to know if someone knows. Qt: open the source code of a function? OpenCV: documentation for the implemented algorithms available?

Comment: This seems like two separate questions. You should perhaps edit the first part out and only ask about the "main problem". Then ask a new question about the first issue. Also, if you ask about code, it's good include the code which shows the wrong behavior...

Comment: In Qt Creator, Ctrl-click the function name to jump to definition.  On mac, CMD-click.

Comment: @Pete thx but if i cmd-click on for example "stereoRectifyUncalibrated" all i see is this "CV_EXPORTS_W bool stereoRectifyUncalibrated( InputArray points1, InputArray point... );" but i like to read what they have done what the source code is.. any way to get there? thx

Comment: @3gfisch Possibly try debugging the code & stepping into the call.  Alternatively do an 'advanced' find on the folder containing the opencv source code for e.g. stereoRectifyUncalibrated.  The problem is that you have probably built the opencv library separately to the Qt project and it doesn't know where the source code is.  Maybe there is a way of telling it where the opencv files are, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

so i found out what the Q matrix constrains here:
[Using OpenCV to generate 3d points (assuming frontal parallel configuration)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11406849/3858076)

all these parameters are given by the single camera calibration:
c_x , c_y , f

and the baseline is what i have measured:
T_x

so this works for now, only the units are not that clear to me, i have used them form single camera calib which are in px and set the baseline in meters, divided the disparity map by 16, but it seams not the right scale..

by the way the disparity map above was wrong ^^ and now it looks better. you have to do a anti Shearing Transform cause the stereoRectifyUncalibrated is Shearing your image (not documented?).
described in this paper at "7 Shearing Transform" by Charles Loop Zhengyou Zhang:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/Zhang/Papers/TR99-21.pdf

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkuJi.jpg