# 3D Recontruction from only two 2D images w/ iPhone 7 camera

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

**The Main Problem:**

Reconstruct an object from only 2 images (at least what can be perceived from the 2 images).

**About Camera:**

I'm using an iPhone 7 camera and I'm taking my own pictures meaning I can calibrate my camera. I can obtain the focal length (4mm) and sensor width (3.99mm) from : https://www.anandtech.com/show/10685/the-iphone-7-and-iphone-7-plus-review/6. I also know I can get my focal length in pixels from these known values and my c_x, and c_y  from the width and height I'm not sure if calibration is correct.

**My current approach:**

I'm following a very similar approach as the one used in this post: [3D reconstruction from 2 images with baseline and single camera calibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852151/3d-reconstruction-from-2-images-with-baseline-and-single-camera-calibration?rq=1)

Algorithm:

`criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03)`

`feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100, qualityLevel = 0.3, minDistance = 7, blockSize = 7 )`

`lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),maxLevel = 20, criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))`

- Corner detection from left image using `enter code here`enter code here `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,mask = None, **feature_params)`
- Refine corners found using `corners1= cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners1,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)`
- Find corners on the right image using optical flow `corners_r, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(gray, r_gray, corners1, None, **lk_params)`
- Keep only the good points `good_left = corners1[st==1]` and `good_right = corners_r[st==1]` ( [Feature match images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3haU.jpg))
- Find the fundamental matrix from the selected points `F, mask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(good_left,good_right,cv2.FM_RANSAC)`
- Calculate H1, H2 for rectification of the images using `_,H1,H2=cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated(good_left,
                                    good_right,
                                    F,
                                    right.shape[:2],
                                    threshold=5.0)`
- Rectify images `new_left = cv2.warpPerspective(img5,H1,img5.shape[:2],cv2.INTER_LINEAR or cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
  new_right= cv2.warpPerspective(img3,H2,img3.shape[:2],cv2.INTER_LINEAR or cv2.INTER_NEAREST)`  (Images depicted below Fig.1)
- Calculate disparity map using `sgbm` in opencv.
- Reconstruct 3D object using `reprojectImageTo3D`

**Problems:**

- Currently not un-distorting images since using my camera matrix `array([[  3.25203085e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   1.54093581e+03],
     [  0.00000000e+00,   3.26746422e+03,   1.91792736e+03],
     [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00]])` and dist_coeffs `array([[ 0.16860882, -1.25881837, -0.01130431, -0.01046869,  2.09480747]])` distorts my images. Calculated these values using 46 images of the chessboard pattern at different angles and perspectives.
- Using warpPerspective with H1 and H2 for corresponding images shears the image a bit much. [Look at sheared images here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3hbh.png) (Fig.1)

**Questions:**

- I obtained `total error:  0.457120388`(not bad i think) for camera calibration following the steps here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html 
  Is this a good error ?
- Is the shearing in my images how it actually should look? I'm thinking this extra shearing comes from the feature matching using optical flow and maybe there are a couple features that don't truly match. What are good ways of filtering them even more to be more precise? I heard I can also use Zhang's algorithm to correct this shearing but not sure how I would apply that. This needs to work for other images as well meaning I want to have a more robust approach not just to these two images if possible.

Sorry if wasn't as precise, please let me know if you need more information. I have also been searching around for answers for a while so I'm only asking this question because I have nowhere else to turn so far.

Any help is much appreciated in advance. Thank you guys!

Comment: Hello maxmine11.. a lot of effort is put in your question. But.. finish the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and edit your question in such a way that we see code, errors and reproduce it by testing it. From there we can help and try to solve the issue at hand with you. Hint for your algorithm: see for that [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Hi @ZF007, thanks for the advice. I made some changes to my question to make it more clear. Also, the errors I'm getting are due to the procedure I'm using (most likely not right) rather than the actual code which is why I was trying to focus on conveying that but I'm open to more critique as I want improve myself :)  Thanks again!

Comment: What you are trying to do is pretty difficult. Step 1 is always to get your calibration right, which it looks like you're on the path to. I've also had good luck with April cal, which is sometimes easier to use than OpenCV's calibration. april.eecs.umich.edu/wiki/Camera_suite. The second part, is to determine if you really need to take only two images and nothing else. Can you get other data that might tell you how the camera has moved? Without other data the scale factor will be difficult. Eg how can you tell the difference between an object and a tiny photo of the object?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. Your calibration RMSE seems a little high for comfort. You should aim for 0.1 pixels. I suggest to plot the residual vectors image by image and see if you have outliers. See also more recommendations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821056/1435240).
2. Distortion coefficients are ordinarily not published. You need to calibrate to get them.
3. The "shearing" you observe is due to the rectification. You can visually check the epipolar error without rectifying - choose pixel x in one image, draw the corresponding epipolar line in the other image, and see if it passes for pixel x' matching x. Repeat for a few x.
4. The visual check for rectified images is whether corresponding rows of the two images are aligned.

Comment: Hi @FrancescoCallari thanks for the advice on the calibration, I will try that!. Regarding the shearing I understand the conjugal epipolar lines must line up with each other but I was wondering if there was a more general fix for this shearing due to the rectification instead of checking that every point lies on its corresponding epipolar line? Idk if this will be efficient if I need to that every single time I take two pictures of an object.   Thanks again for taking your time to help me!