# visualizing the depth map in matlab and get the depth of an object in mm

Tags: matlab, depth, matlab-cvst, disparity-mapping

what is the best way to visualize the depth map in MATLAB to find the depth of an object in millimeters?
I am using the formula in [How Field of view changes depth estimation in stereo vision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421003/how-field-of-view-changes-depth-estimation-in-stereo-vision) to calculate depth from disparity. now I want to measure the depth of an object in the depth map. all units are in mm. my disparity map is 786*1126 single. my depth map is the same size. I am plotting them using imagesc in MATLAB. but that does not give me any idea on the depth of an object. any help is appreciated.

Comment: try using surf. or you can change you image to grayscale.

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried that but the results were not promising. I think I need to check my disparity results again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the depth map into a set of 3D points, and then use `plot3()` or `scatter3()` to plot the points in 3D. If you want to assign the colors from the image to the points, that will take additional work.  Take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html).

Comment: how can I plot3() or scatter() a matrix that is not square size? my depth map is a 791*1126 single matrix in MATLAB. when I try this it does not work: X=1:size(depthMap,1);
Y=1:size(depthMap,2);
Z=depthMap;
figure, scatter(X,Y,Z)

Comment: `plot3` and `scatter3` both take x, y, and z coordinates of your points as separate vectors.

Comment: can you please clarify? if I have a matrix Z of size 791*1126, how can I plot it using scatter3?

Comment: You can't.  You need the corresponding matrix X and matrix Y. You would need to put together matrix Q from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406849/using-opencv-to-generate-3d-points-assuming-frontal-parallel-configuration

Comment: Better yet, calibrate your cameras and do the reconstruction using `reconstructScene()` function as in this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html